# Change text color of UIButton in CalloutAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I use this code to create a `UIButton` in my `CalloutView`.

```
var button  = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
            button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            button.setTitle("No", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            anView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
```

How can I change the text color of `UIButton`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the title/text color of a [`UIButton`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitleColor:forState:) like so:

```
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```